# (Android) How to make a dialogue asking the user's current password before allowing the user to update the password?

Tags: javascript, java, android, sqlite, change-password

I want to make an application to lock apps. So, before the user can update the password, I want the user to enter the current password first before letting the user to update a new password for security.

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        update_pass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cn);
                builder.setTitle("Enter Current Password");

                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(cn);
                // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                builder.setView(input);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = input.getText().toString();

                        if(m_Text.isEmpty()){

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else{

                            int zz = db.getAllData(m_Text);
                            db.insertData(m_Text);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password updated successfully "  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }






                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();




            }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cn);
                builder.setTitle("Enter Password");

                // Set up the input
                final EditText input = new EditText(cn);
                // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
                input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
                builder.setView(input);

                // Set up the buttons
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        m_Text = input.getText().toString();

                        if(m_Text.isEmpty()){

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                        else{

                            int zz = db.deleteData(m_Text);
                            db.insertData(m_Text);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password updated successfully "  , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }






                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                builder.show();




            }
        });





    }



    // check your background services
    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i ("Service status", "Running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i ("Service status", "Not running");
        return false;
    }



    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if(!isAccessGranted()){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("USAGE_STATS Permission")
                    .setMessage("Allow USAGE_STATS Permission in Setting")
                    .setPositiveButton("Allow", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // action
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Abort", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            //
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
        else if(pass.isEmpty()){


            update_pass.setText("Set Password");

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(cn);
            builder.setTitle("Enter Password");

             // Set up the input
            final EditText input = new EditText(cn);
            // Specify the type of input expected; this, for example, sets the input as a password, and will mask the text
            input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
            builder.setView(input);

            // Set up the buttons
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    m_Text = input.getText().toString();

                    if(m_Text.isEmpty()){

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password can't be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                      boolean tt =  db.insertData(m_Text);
                      pass.add(m_Text);
                      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,   "password added successfully "+m_Text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      update_pass.setText("Update Password");

                    }






                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            builder.show();



        }
```

Here is the Password_Database.java

```
public class Password_Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    // this is database class, database is sqlite
    // embedded in android studio

    // database name
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pass_data.db";
    // table name
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "password_table";

    // columns
    public static final String col1 = "password";


    // constructor
    public Password_Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        // SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    // create table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "  + TABLE_NAME + "( password TEXT  )  ");
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    }


    // insert data into table
    public boolean insertData(String name) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(col1,name);


        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null ,contentValues);
        db.close();

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }

    }


    // read data from table
    public Cursor getAllData(String m_Text){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }






    // update data in table

    public boolean updateData(String name, String pass){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues, col1+" =?", new String[]{name});
        return true;
    }



    // delete data from table
    public Integer deleteData(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int i = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, col1 +" =?", new String[]{name});
        return i;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think having an SQL database would not be so good for this kind of application. Try to use SharedPreferences instead then let the user input his old password in EditText and check it